# Running Standalone Jar need to add jar on server to run

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I created a spring boot job which relies on properties on the server and I can get it to run like so, no modifying manifest.

/bin/java -Dspring.config.location=/var/tmp/com.jdbc.properties -jar my.jar

and it works. But the application relies upon another jar that is an internal jar that lives under /usr/local/share/jni/foo.jar which I want to add to this mix.

I have tried countless runs trying such things as:
java -cp /usr/local/share/jni/foo.jar -Dspring(picking up original line)

When I start to google this, it takes me on magical tours of running:
'org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher'
or
'org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher'
then mucking with manifest etc.

Spent last 4 hours with no success. Is there a best practice to run a standalone jar that needs to consume remote properties file and an additional jar file? Would like to keep it simple if possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring Boot and want to have a Fat-jar that encapsulates all your dependencies, the best way is to add the required Jar as a dependency to your project.

Assuming you are using Maven to build your project, the "foo.jar" needs to be added as a Maven dependency to your project. Then, spring Boot maven plugin will pick up the jar and includes it in your Fat-jar.

Even if the "foo.jar" does not exist in any Maven repo, you still can add it manually to your local Maven repo using the Maven command mvn install:install-file ([See Maven doc](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `foo.jar` as a `provided` dependency within your maven/gradle dependencies and building the project as executable war file?

See [spring boot's maven plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging) description of building executable war files.

Comment: I made foo.jar as provided, then found out that you have to also exclude it the spring-boot-maven-plugin or else it shows up in the jar. I use the jar file locally to build, but have to ensure it only lives on the server when making the call. So this has been dealt with.  As far as building a war, I am not sure if that is an option, as this is deployed on a jvm not a container. We have a bunch of Spring Batch jobs running there, this is the first time for running a Spring boot as a jar. I may just bail out on this boot objective, causing too much angst in my life. Thanks for response.

Answer (score 0):

Overall. Run spring boot standalone jar on a Linux server. Additionally read the database properties from a static file on the server, and path in a jar file that adds functionality that only lives on the server. Cannot include in the boot lib.

command line run (will convert to shell) and ran.

`/path/to/..openjdk-1.7.0.55.x86_64/bin/java -cp /usr/somewhere/jni/Foo.jar:/path/where/lib/MYBOOTJAR.jar org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher --spring.config.location=/path/to/properties/on/server/com.xxx.yyy.zzz.jdbc.properties`

Seems like using the JarLauncher (no modifications to manifest, except excluding the Foo.jar from local)

Hope this  helps someone else.